# Как сверстать картинку по ширине и высоте в квадратный див не растягивая?

Tags: php, css, img

Добрый день! Помогите с верской картинки.
Есть квадратный див с картинкой (точнее галереей) в которой есть картинки как прямоугольные вертикальные и горизонтальные. Как вместить не растягивая их в квадратныйдив.Если ширину ствить 100% тогда горизонтальные картинки получаются обрезанные и наоборот. CSS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: img{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%} и центрируйте картинку в центр блока...

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
}

img {
  border: #f00 solid 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/518803/129310280/stock-photo-a-bird-s-eye-view-of-shanghai-at-dusk-129310280.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2324765/484954783/stock-photo-top-view-aerial-photo-from-flying-drone-of-a-hongkong-global-city-with-development-buildings-484954783.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/691720/101264377/stock-photo-new-york-city-street-old-style-image-101264377.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот несколько вариантов:

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  border: 4px solid red;
  line-height:150px;
}

.one img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.two {
  border: 4px solid green;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:none;
}

.three {
  border: 4px solid orange;
}

.three img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-position: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><img src="http://nwlife.ru/wp-content/gallery/fotooboi-priroda/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-105.jpg"></div>

<div class="one"><img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_megli86khL1rebzwto1_1280.jpg"></div>

<br><div class="two" style="background-image:url(http://nwlife.ru/wp-content/gallery/fotooboi-priroda/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-105.jpg)"></div>

<div class="two" style="background-image:url(http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_megli86khL1rebzwto1_1280.jpg)"></div>

<br><div class="three"><img src="http://nwlife.ru/wp-content/gallery/fotooboi-priroda/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-105.jpg"></div>

<div class="three"><img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_megli86khL1rebzwto1_1280.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я неправильно вас понял, но вот это свойство должно помочь

background-size: cover;

И отцентрировать background-position: center;